# Pre-added Whitespaces in XML on first line only

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am facing an issue while generating XML through Java code. I am printing the xml directly onto webpage to present the stats. The first line of the generated XML is always having some spaces at the start which makes the XML look weird. How do I remove the same. I tried removing the xml line but still whatever be the first line it has pre white spaces.

Please let me now how do i remove it

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<headNode>
  <statsHead1>
    <totalCount>0.05</totalCount>
  </statsHead1>
  <statsHead2>
    <statsSubHead1>
      <count1>0</count1>
      <count2>0.0</count2>
    </statsSubHead1>
    <statsSubHead2>
      <count1>0</count1>
      <count2>0.0</count2>
    </statsSubHead2>
    <totalcount1>0</totalcount1>
    <totalcount2>0.0</totalcount2>
  </statsHead2>
</headNode>
```

Code that I use is

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StringWriter outWriter = new StringWriter();
Result result = new StreamResult(outWriter);
transformer.transform(source, result);
return outWriter.toString();
```

Comment: What is your generator?

Comment: Just added the code

Comment: You can see one way of implementation here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/

Comment: This is what is referred in the first place.